# In R, remove rows where subtraction of values between contiguous values in same column excede a value

Tags: r, rows

I have a data frame in R consisting in 5 columns and 30000 rows. One column, called "pos", has this kind of values sorted in ascending order:

```
pos

785989
888659
918573
949608
990417
```

I would like to remove all rows where the difference between a "x" value in "pos" (in a "n" row) and the anterior value in the "n-1" row or the difference between the posterior value in "n+1" row and "x" is greater than, lets say, 100000. Eg: in the input example, 888659-785989 = 102670 > 100000, therefore rows containing 888659 and 785989 values should be removed.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are the numbers sorted in increasing order in the real data as in the example?

Comment: yes @PierreLafortune

Comment: It worked great @Pierre Lafortune, but your script only returns the values. I would like to get a new data frame including the 5 columns without the removed rows. Thanks very much

Comment: The subset function added

Comment: Thanks ! @PierreLafortune

Comment: Hi @PierreLafortune. I have some 27000 rows left after running the diff_set function. Is there any way of creating the new data frame including this 27000 rows from the 5 columns other than using the "scan" function?. The problem with "scan" is that I have to insert a text of 27000 values. I am new to R, thanks very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a user function that takes the `diff` of a vector and checks a conditional gap provided by the user:

```
diff_set <- function(x, gap) {
  ind <- c(F, diff(x) > gap)
  if(sum(ind) == 0) return(!ind)
  subst <- x[-unique(c(which(ind), which(ind)-1))]
  x %in% subst
}

df1[diff_set(df1$x, 1e5),]
       x y
3 918573 C
4 949608 D
5 990417 E
```

**Data**

```
x <- scan(text="785989
888659
          918573
          949608
          990417")
df1 <- data.frame(x, y=LETTERS[1:5])
```